# PHP return first three elements in an array then another three

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of 20 elements and each element in the array holds an image. I'm making it so the image sizes alternate. Three images should be medium size, then next four are small, and 7th is large. Pattern should continue till end of the array. Right now I have it working so that every 7th image is large, and the rest are small. I'm not sure what the best way would be to set up the medium images. So:
Array[]

```
[0]
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
[5]
[6]
[7]
[8]
[9]
[10]
[11]
[12]
[13]
[14]
[15]
[16]
[17]
[18]
[19]
[20]
```

I would want [0], [1], [2], [8],[9],[10],[15],[16],[17] to all be medium sized.

Here's my code below.

```
        foreach ($images as $image ) {
                $img_size = "small";
                if($i !==0 && $i % 7 == 0) {
                    $img_size = "large";
                }else{
                    $img_size = $img_size;
                }
        }
```

Comment: Cool, what have you tried? Show us your code that's not working.

Comment: cool project, what is the question though?

Comment: updated post with more info. hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: array_chunk is probably going to be useful for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some if/else logic:

```
<?php

$m = 3;
$s = 7;
$l = 8;

$counter = 1;
for($i=0;$i<=20;$i++){
    if($counter <= $m){
        $img_size = "medium";
    }elseif($counter <= $s){
        $img_size = "small";
    }else{
        $img_size = "large";
    }
    if($counter == $l) $counter = 0;

    $counter++;
    echo "i = $i and img_size = $img_size <br>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Added the if statements to my original foreach loop and this worked great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$i = 0;
$count = count($a)-1; // get the maximum index of array $a

while ($i <= $count) {

    echo $a[i];
    if ($i+1 <= $count) echo $a[$i+1];
    if ($i+2 <= $count) echo $a[$i+2];

    $i+=8;
} // while
```